# echo anchor tag with query string php and output $date in a calendar

Tags: php, string, anchor

This is my first time asking a question, so please take that into consideration if I have done this wrong. Please look this over and explain where I am going wrong.
I can display the ending dates of the previous month in the first week of the current month for a calendar row.  But I need to include a query string in the anchor tag that is being echo'd with the current $print_date.  These are the different ways I have already attempted without success.  The date is formatted 'YYYY-M-D'

```
while ( $start_point > 0 ) 
{   
    // Returns what day of the week 'w' (numeric 0-6), using the date function.
    $day_of_week = date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));    
    // To get the last Sunday of the previous month use:
    $sun_prev_month = date('d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, (1 - $day_of_week), $year));
    // Fills the dates, starting on Sunday for the end of previous month
    $print_date = $sun_prev_month;      
    for ($i = 0; $i < $day_of_week; ++$i)
    {                       
        //echo '<td class="shade"><a href="/~seeleyja/CSCI-2910/calendar4.php?date=' . $year . '-' . ($month-1) . '-' . $print_date  . '">'. $print_date . '</a></td>';
                ?>
        <td><a href="/~seeleyja/CSCI-2910/calendar4.php?<?=htmlspecialchars($prev_month);?>"> $print_date </a></td>;
        <?php
        //echo '<td class="shade"><a href="/~seeleyja/CSCI-2910/calendar4.php?date=$prev_month">'. $print_date . '</a></td>';
        //echo '<td class="shade"><a href="/~seeleyja/CSCI-2910/calendar4.php?date=' . $year . '-' . ($month-1) . '-' . $print_date . '">'. $print_date . '</a></td>';
        --$start_point;
        $print_date++;                      
        $day_of_week_counter++;                             
    }
}
```

Comment: And ... what is the problem?

Comment: are you requiring this:



echo"
 <td class='shade'>
  <a href='/~seeleyja/CSCI-2910/calendar4.php?date=$year-$month-1-$print_date'></a>
 </td>
";

Comment: I am not able to get the correct response when clicking the date on the calendar.  Move from one date in the month to another.  The class='shade' is to highlight the day that are not in the current month being displayed.  I am able to move months and years but not the days along with indicating the day being selected.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using an undefined variable $prev_month, and have forgotten the "date" parameter in the URL. Is it possible you meant to use $sun_prev_month or $print_date?